# FreeForm Pro 4.2.0 form fields prepulated with "value"

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm trying to get the fields that appear on my contact form to be pre-populated using the standard HTML "Value" attribute, but can not figure out how to get the freeform:field declaration to pass it on.

I currently have the following in my form code:
{freeform:field:name value="test"}

Here is the form online as of right now:
http://sustainablefurnishings.com/contact_us/

The "value" is not populated in the code and therefore doesn't appear in the field.

How can the "Value" be set for a form field using the FreeForm Pro tools? Am I missing something in their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for is default_value:

```
{freeform:field:my_field default_value=""}
```

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_field_field_name

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: My pleasure. Make sure to mark this answer as the official/best answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Using Composer Hidden Fields?

If you found this answer whilst searching for a solution to this problem for hidden fields in Composer, check out Solspace's other answer over here:

**[Getting channel TITLE tag value in Freeform Pro Composer hidden input field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34177/getting-channel-title-tag-value-in-freeform-pro-composer-hidden-input-field)**