# Getting channel TITLE tag value in Freeform Pro Composer hidden input field

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, composer, composer-template

I have created a Freeform field called **title_tag** and have set the type to "hidden". In the field config settings, when selecting "Hidden Field" as the type, the field options allows you to set the Default Incoming Data:

> Allowed data are ExpressionEngine tags and brackets and special
>   fields. All HTML will be removed from this setting.

As my form is a field type in my channel, I have set the default value to `{title}`

[image]

I have then added the field to my form:

[image]

However, the Title of the channel entry is not pulling through:

[image]

I'm assuming it's something simple that I've missed but can't seem to identify what I've done wrong and why the `{title}` tag isn't pulling in the Title as the value for the hidden input when it clearly says in the Field Options that this can be done.

**VERSION DETAILS:**

ExpressionEngine: 2.10.1
Freeform Pro: 4.2.3

Comment: Request for help posted to Twitter :) https://twitter.com/Dan_Treasure/status/649414043111833600

Answer (score 2):

Do you have anything in the URL that allows you to find the channel entry using `{exp:channel:entries}`? If so, you could use this and use the `{exp:channel:entries}` inside the hidden field to retrieve the entry title that is loading your Composer Freeform form.

For example, if you have your channel entry's ID in segment_3, you could put the following as the value of your Freeform hidden field:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{segment_3}" dynamic="no"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

There's no other way for Composer to "figure out" it's coming from a channel entry custom field (i.e. `{title}` on its own won't be enough).

Comment: What if the form tag is being rendered inside a `{exp:channel:entries}` tag already? Surely then it should be possible to pick up the entry's variables?

Comment: Not if the form is loaded from the Channel Entry _Freeform custom field_. `{exp:channel:entries}` parses the Freeform custom field to Freeform form code, and Freeform then parses its form code: unfortunately `{title}` on its own then comes too late to be parsed.

Comment: In this case, the form _isn't_ loaded from the Channel Entry Freeform custom field... it's 'manually' loaded in the template using Freeform template tags.

Comment: So `{exp:freeform:composer}` inside `{exp:channel:entries}`? Can you post your code in your question/OP? Have you also tried using `parse="inward"` on `{exp:freeform:composer}` to see if the form can't be parsed first, with an unparsed `{title}`, and then _that_ gets parsed by `{exp:channel:entries}`?